# I don't get chosen-cakephp it working in simple application

Tags: cakephp, jquery-chosen

I am new to CakePHP, MVC and web developing in general (JQuery, etc), altough I have more than 15 years programming non web applications and some little knowledge of PHP.

In order to learn, I am developing a simple school project containing 3 tables (courses, professors, courses_professors).

I have "baked all" and got a nice CRUD application which works perfectly.

Now I am trying to improve select boxes userfriendliness provided by harvesthq/chosen by using [Chosen-CakePHP](https://github.com/paulredmond/chosen-cakephp).

I have followed the instructions for installation and setup of the plugin at https://github.com/paulredmond/chosen-cakephp, but I am not sure about what more steps should I follow in order to make it work. Btw. I understand creating a custom class is optional.

To be true, I expected that modifing /app/Controller/AppController.php as explained in would be enough to see the new select boxes working, but the application works just as it did before adding the plugin.

The code contained in /app/Controller/AppController.php is the following (comments removed):

```
App::uses('Controller', 'Controller');

class AppController extends Controller {

    public $helpers = array('Chosen.Chosen');    

}
```

app/Config/bootstrap.php contains:

```
./...

CakePlugin::load('DebugKit');
CakePlugin::load('Chosen');

./...
```

I have been googling for 2 days, but I don't get the idea.

**Do I need to modify any code generated by bake? Do I need to modify anyother files?**

I guess my lack of knowledge in the field is quite relevant. Should you reccomend me an essential previous reading or exercise, any reccomendation is welcome.

Any indications would be appreciated.

Thanks for your help,
ivan

Answer (score 0):

I have never work with the plugin you mention, but look at the examples in the link you provided

(in the view)

```
echo $this->Chosen->select(
    'Article.category_id',
    array(1 => 'Category 1', 2 => 'Category 2'),
    array('data-placeholder' => 'Pick categories...', 'multiple' => true)
);
```

The helper used is not `$this->Form->input`, as it comes with baking, it's `$this->Chosen->select`. So my guess is "yes, you need to modify the code generated by bake".

Try that, and if it doesn't work, update your question with the code you tried for the view and if it gives you any (new) error.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need a plugin to get such a small functionality for your forms.

1. First you need to download a [Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) package.
2. Open your *webroot* folder and put there all dependent js, css files that comes with package
3. Open default layout file app/Views/Layouts/default.php (if you "baked all" that should be default layout file)
4. Read about inserting js, and css files into your layout here [Html Helper](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html#HtmlHelper%3a%3acss)
   Syntax is simple:
   This code:

   echo $this->Html->css('forms');

Outputs:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/forms.css" />
```

Similar for js files..

1. Add this code to layout footer

   $(".chzn-select").chosen();

or header (but then you need to wrap it with [document.ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) ;

1. In your baked view files add class .chzn-select to select form elements

   echo $this->Form->input('Model.field', array(
       'type' => 'select',
       'multiple' => true,
       'class' => 'chzn-select'
   ));

If you just started learning, it's to early to just "bake all"